# segmentation fault while running cython on python3-- gdb output

Tags: gdb, cython, python-3.4

I have been trying to trace the source of a segfault in a cython program that I inherited. I have implemented gdb under python3  by executing `gdb python3` then `run my_file.py` and got this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__pyx_f_7sklearn_5utils_25graph_shortest_path_leftmost_sibling (__pyx_v_node=<optimised out>)
at /home/my_name/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pyrex/sklearn/utils/graph_shortest_path_strat.c:3195
3195        __pyx_t_1 = (__pyx_v_temp->left_sibling != 0);
```

---

Thanks @Veedrac 
The call appears as follows:

```
landmark_points=[random.randint(0,kng.shape[0]) for r in range(self.number_landmark_points)]     
self.dist_matrix_=graph_shortest_path_strat(kng,landmark_points,method=self.path_method,directed=F‌​alse).
```

Basically instead of calculating the distances between every single point in a graph I want to calculate the distance between all points and a limited number of points defined in an array. where landmark_points is an array of integers kng is a graph of nearest neighbors

```
kng = kneighbors_graph(self.nbrs_, self.n_neighbors,mode='distance')
```

the graph_shortest_path is a .pyx code. And I am using version is 0.15.1

Comment: Thanks @Veedrac 
    landmark_points=[random.randint(0,kng.shape[0]) for r in range(self.number_landmark_points)]
    self.dist_matrix_ = graph_shortest_path_strat(kng,landmark_points,method=self.path_method,directed=False). Basically instead of caculating the distances between every single point in a graph I want to calculate the distance between all points and a limited number of points defined in an array.

where landmark_points is an array of integers
kng is a graph of nearest neighbors

    kng = kneighbors_graph(self.nbrs_, self.n_neighbors,mode='distance')

Comment: the graph_shortest_path is a .pyx code. And I am using version is 0.15.1

Comment: oops, thanks have done that

Comment: How big are the inputs to `graph_shortest_path_strat`?

Comment: so, kng is a 4000 x 4000 matrix, and landmark_points is 2000 in length

Comment: Ehhh... Why you gotta' make this so hard? :P If you just crop the arrays to be smaller, does the problem still reproduce? If so, how small can you make them?

Comment: @Veedrac thanks for your help. I actually traced the error to the fact that I was using random.randint, when I should have been generating unique random integers with random.sample

Comment: Glad to have helped... or tried, as it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Veedrac thanks for your help. I actually traced the error to the fact that I was using random.randint, when I should have been generating unique random integers with random.sample.